# Wolfram alpha gives two different answers for $\int^{\infty}_{-\infty} x \frac{1}{\pi} e^{-(\ln(x) - 0.3)^2} | \frac{1}{x}|dx$

Tags: wolfram-alpha

So, I'm trying to calculate $$\int^{\infty}_{-\infty} x  \frac{1}{\pi} e^{-(\ln(x) - 0.3)^2}  \left| \frac{1}{x}\right|dx$$

When I input that into WA, it loads for a bit, then shows this result: [image: Result 1]

Just to almost instantly change to this other result: [image: Result 2]

And I can't make sense of why. Why does this calculation give two results for the same input?

Thanks!

In case someone wants to replicate it, the natural language is:
Integrate[1/π*x*Exp[-Power[(ln(x)-0.3),2]]* Abs[1/x],{x,-∞,∞}]

Comment: What is the exact text you enter in WA?

Comment: @dxiv I used the math input mode. The text can be seen in the upper part of both images.

Comment: I meant the plain text. What shows in the images is reformatted already, and it's not enough for someone to duplicate what you are getting.

Comment: @dxiv oh, sorry, I'm not used to WA. When I select natural language, I get this: Integrate[1/π*x*Exp[-Power[(ln(x)-0.3),2]]* Abs[1/x],{x,-∞,∞}]

Comment: Perhaps because $\,1/\pi x\,$ could mean $\,1/(\pi x)\,$ or $\,(1/\pi)x\,$ depending on how it is parsed.

Comment: What does $\log(x)$ mean when $x≤0$?

Comment: How exactly is $\log x$ defined for $x \le 0$?  If you are integrating over the real line, your integrand is complex-valued on this interval.

Comment: @heropup I generaly use ln(abs(x))

Comment: @dxiv your link works for me and does exactly what op says

Comment: @DavidP It works *now*, indeed, so I removed the previous comment. Guess Brian Moehring was right.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

As I alluded to in the comments section, you did not define how the integrand $$f(x) = \frac{x}{\pi |x|} e^{-\left(\log x - \frac{3}{10}\right)^2}$$ is defined for $x \le 0$.  On this interval, you would have the principal branch $$\log x = \log |x| + \pi i,$$ hence $$\left( \log x - \frac{3}{10} \right)^2 = \left( \log^2 |x| - \frac{3}{5} \log |x| - \pi^2 + \frac{9}{100} \right) + \left( 2\pi \log |x| - \frac{3\pi}{5} \right)i.$$  When integrated, the real part converges, but the imaginary part does not.

Alternatively, if you define

$$g(x) = \frac{x}{\pi|x|} e^{-\left(\log |x| - \frac{3}{10}\right)^2},$$ then this function is real and well-defined (except for a removable singularity at $x = 0$); but it is also clearly an odd function satisfying $g(-x) = -g(x)$, thus $$\int_{x=-\infty}^\infty g(x) \, dx = 0.$$

If the interval of integration is instead $(0, \infty)$, then

$$\int_{x=0}^\infty f(x) \, dx = \frac{e^{11/20}}{\sqrt{\pi}} \approx 0.977883.$$

Twice this value is the other result you obtained, approximately $1.95577$.

What this shows is that ill-defined inputs can yield unreliable or nonsensical outputs.

Comment: Thanks! I was just wondering why it showed a result only to then change it, but your explanation makes a lot of sense. Again, thanks a lot.